# Displaying labels with a recursive filter in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, labeling, overlapping-features

I display the labels of a point layer (layer "q").
With a command found on the site, I know how to filter the labels if they intersect an object from another layer (layer "p1").
On the other hand, when there are several objects it no longer works (layer "p2").

Does anyone have an idea for a recursive filter?

The expression I tried:

```
case
when intersects ($geometry, geometry (get_feature ('p2', 'ccogrm',4)))
then 1 
else 0
end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To only show labels that intersect with layer `p1` or layer `p2`, use this expression in <kbd>Placement</kbd> tab for data defined `Show label` setting:

```
overlay_intersects ('p1') or overlay_intersects ('p2')
```

*Only points intersecting layer `p1` (blue) or `p2` (yellow) are labeled:*
[image]

To include all polygon layers in the project and to avoid repeating `layer1 or layer2` etc., use this expression that includes automatically all layers of type polygon:

```
array_contains(
    array_foreach(
        array_foreach (
            @layers,
            if (
                layer_property (@element,'geometry_type') = 'Polygon',
                @element,
                @layer
            )
        ),
        overlay_intersects (@element)
    ), 
    true
)
```

*Each polygon is a different layer. Only points that overlap one of the polygon layers are labeled, based on the expression above:*

[image]